# objc tableheader hides tablerows?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, row, uitableview

I have a tableView where I added a header section. Somehow the header hides the rows... When I remove the header section, the rows are visible. When I add the header section, it hides the rows. Normally the rows shall be visible after the header section. I have no glue why this does not work...

I have a similar tableView and there it works perfectly with the same setup, header and rows are displayed.

**The table header section and rows shall be visible at the same time. How can I do this?**
Below the code:

#### LocationViewController.h

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SingletonClass.h"
#import "WebApi.h"
#import <AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>

@interface LocationViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) SingletonClass *sshare;
@property (nonatomic, strong) WebApi *swebapi;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *locationID;

@end
```

#### LocationViewController.m

```c
#import "LocationViewController.h"

@interface LocationViewController ()

@end

@implementation LocationViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)vinit {

    self.sshare = [SingletonClass sharedInstance];

    self.swebapi = [[WebApi alloc] init];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"reloadDetails" object:nil ];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:NFlocationReload object:nil ];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self vinit]; 
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init]; 

    [self getData]; 
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}

-(void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)message {
    if ([[message name] isEqualToString:@"reloadDetails"]) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    if ([[message name] isEqualToString:NFlocationReload]) {
        DLog(@"%@, lData", self.sshare.lData);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.sshare.lData.count;
}


 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"locationCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

     NSString *foo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %ld", (long)indexPath.row];
     cell.textLabel.text = foo;
     DLog(@"logged: %@", foo);
     cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor]; 

     return cell;
 }

-(void)getData {
    [self.swebapi getLocationStream:self.locationID];
}

#pragma mark table header image and size
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIImageView *BGView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 320, 174)];
    [BGView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 169)];
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];

    NSString *photoURL;

    if (self.sshare.imageDetails) {

        photoURL = self.sshare.imageDetails.url
        [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.jpg"]];
        [BGView addSubview:imageView];

    }
    return BGView;

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's missing a delegate method.  From the docs on `viewForHeaderInSection`: ...

> The returned object can be a UILabel or UIImageView object, as well as
>   a custom view. This method only works correctly when
>   tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: is also implemented.

So add...

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 174;
}
```